# Why did Engineers use a flute to start their spaceship?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus

Why do they use a flute to start their spaceship?
Are the notes played a reference to something else, or are they significant at all?

Comment: It's probably some weird remnant of their culture - I mean, we use *foot pedals* to start our cars, of all things.

Comment: If I ever design a spaceship, it will start by reacting to sung/hummed/played Imperial March.

Comment: @Tacroy I think it would be more appropriate to say we use keys to start our car. Them the pedals are the interface for the mechanics of the car. The key in a mechanical process of starting has little to no meaning except in authenticating the driver. Seen this way the flute, or the notes played are just another authentication method.

Comment: "Authentication", thats the key word of the function of that flute

Comment: Because on the homeworld in prehistoric times they rode giant creatures with which they communicated via music, so naturally that has been carried forward in new technologies.  Source: imagination.

Comment: That flute reminds me shepherds, and scandinavian forests.

Comment: According to the novelisation they initially tried a trombone but rejected it on grounds of silliness.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a far flung, very unofficial theory that just occured to me: It could have been a tribute, a reference to the works of H.P. Lovecraft.

> "[O]utside the ordered universe [is] that amorphous blight of
>   nethermost confusion which blasphemes and bubbles at the center of all
>   infinity—the boundless daemon sultan Azathoth, whose name no lips dare
>   speak aloud, and who gnaws hungrily in inconceivable, unlighted
>   chambers beyond time and space amidst the muffled, maddening beating
>   of vile drums and **the thin monotonous whine of accursed flutes.**"

Source: [Wikipedia ("Azatoth" entry)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azathoth)

(Emphasis mine.)

Okay, coming to think of how much influence Lovecraft's works are said to have on Scott's original *Alien* and the entire franchise, maybe it's not that far fetched. Remember, H.R. Giger's art book that Scott was given during the pre-production of *Alien* was called [**Necronomicon**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necronomicon_%28H._R._Giger%29)...

Comment: If it's not an outright homage, it's used for the same reason - that it's darned creepy.

Answer (score -2):

Ship is alive. That is the ultimate art of creation. Man can create material things, not live things, things that are assembled of other pieces, cut materials, welded materials.. A man work can never repair itself. But man can, man is a machine, an ultimate contraption where every single building block is alive.

"Engineers" were creating living nature, so the sound was the right frequency to communicate and thus activate the ship. That can be understood if one get to analyze the work of Thomas Campbell - My Big TOE.

Greek myths also have a message to us from old days, time when man was four dimensional being, when no language was needed to understand each others, to understand what our cells have to say, what they feel, what they need, what other creatures have to say each others,  or to us, and now we think our technology of cellphones is remarkable...

Anyway, that is why Tesla didn't want to publish the radio communication, but discovering that was a nus-product of a bigger discovery, and always - naturally there are vultures like Marconi and Pupin.

Comment: This answer is barely coherent.

Comment: @Valorum: in fairness, the same description applies to *Prometheus*.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Touché, good sir.